# Changing the image of an UIImage view with a button

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uibutton

Hey, I have an ImageView in my app and I want the user to be able to change the image in that image view by clicking on a button.This is the code I got

In .h

```
@interface BGViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

-(IBAction)img1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)img2:(id)sender;
```

and in .m

```
@synthesize image;

-(IBAction)img1:(id)sender; {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Main.png"];

}

-(IBAction)img2:(id)sender; {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Themes.png"];


}
```

There is one button for each image by the way!

The app builds but when I click on either one of the buttons nothings happens.

Comment: You should name your UIImageView imageView and your UIImage image to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Main.png"];
```

and

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Themes.png"];
```

with

```
image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Main.png"];
```

and

```
 image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Themes.png"];
```

Now it should work fine :)

Answer (score 4):

Simply set the `image` property of the `UIImageView`:

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Themes.png"];
```

You also have a syntax error in your method implementations, get rid of the semicolon (`;`) after your method signatures.

If I were designing this class, I'd use one action method and use the `tag` property of the `sender` argument to index into an array of `NSString` objects. (For the first button, the `tag` would be `0`, while the second would be `1`, etc.)

You should rename your `UIImageView` ivar to `imageView` to reduce ambiguity.

```
@interface BGViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

-(IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation BGViewController 

NSString *images[] = {
   @"Main.png",
   @"Themes.png"
};

@synthesize imageView;

-(IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender {
  imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: images[sender.tag]];
}

@end
```

Comment: Ok Thanks! If I would like to change the image with a UIScrollView how would I do that?

Comment: @Sweppi You'll need to provide some more detail on what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Maybe this video explains it better: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WO9NRIHU6oQ&feature=related

Comment: @Sweppi Some code would be good. Please show me what you've already done.

Comment: I just noticed I'd accidentally left some semicolons at the end of my method signatures in the implementation file, but it's been working find and doesn't seem to cause problems.  Is this allowed now?